# There is already an object named ' ' in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running a SQL statement to CREATE a table if this table does not exist in 'sysobjects'. The table creates successfully when it does not exist, however, I get an error when running it once the table then does exist. This table must always remain and not be dropped, this is just for first run instance.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '[tablename]')
    CREATE TABLE [tablename]
    (
    jobID int,
    fileName varchar (255),
    pathName varchar (255),
    );
```

So, once this table is created the script is run again and it will error out on this SQL statement due to the table already existing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: SQL server, sorry. Is there someway to skip the CREATE process if the table does exist? It doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Someone give me down vote but the answer is correct ? , tsk tsk :) anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to avoid errors..

If the table is existing then do not create the table, here is the code for easy checking to avoid errors.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('[tablename]') IS NULL
       BEGIN
          CREATE TABLE '[tablename]'
          (
            jobID int,
            fileName varchar (255),
            pathName varchar (255),
          );
       END
```

If that is newly created table, and you want to check if already existing and you want to DROP and CREATE **(Not Advisable)**

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('[tablename]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [tablename]

          CREATE TABLE '[tablename]'
          (
            jobID int,
            fileName varchar (255),
            pathName varchar (255),
          );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think user would want to drop table if it exists.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas , yup you're correct .. that us only for newly created table, and dropping the table is not advisable, so i modified my answer to make it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you don't need quotes in table name, creation:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '[tablename]')
    CREATE TABLE [tablename]
    (
    jobID int,
    fileName varchar (255),
    pathName varchar (255),
    );
```

you are creating a table named `'[tablename]'` and you are looking for a table named `[tablename]`.

Comment: Sorry, I entered those quotes in by mistake on the post. The statement doesn't seem to skip the CREATE process when the table already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid square brackets(**'[' & ']'**) at the time of checking tables

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'tablename')
CREATE TABLE [tablename]
(
jobID int,
fileName varchar (255),
pathName varchar (255),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

your question really amazing... :)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'tablename')
Begin
    CREATE TABLE tablename
    (
    jobID int,
    fileName varchar (255),
    pathName varchar (255),
    )
End
Go
```

I think [ & ] are making you confuse :)